# Handling third-party API requests in End-to-End testing

Tags: rest, api, testing, e2e-testing

I want to test my Rest API with end-to-end tests. As I understand, the difference between integration tests is that we don't do in-memory system configuration, but use real test DB and network requests.

But I can't understand how to handle third-party API requests(like GitHub or Bitbucket API).

Is it a normal practice to create a fake Github account with fake data that would be fetched by my tests ?

And what to do with access tokens, not all services are public and even public services can fail with rate limit.

Comment: If design is SOLID, the 3rd party dependencies are abstracted and decoupled so swapping them out for mocks is a non issue. You understanding of integration tests and end to end sounds a little misguided.

Comment: I think the common solution is to mock 3rd party responses. If the services are paid try with sandbox. It depends what are the requirements you are facing. Can you provide more information?

Comment: ok, I came to the answer that we don't mock anything in e2e testing. But the question about tokens is still opened..

Comment: @EnthusiasticDeveloper how did you came to this conclusion? it might be the right one in some cases, but sometimes relying on external service could make your test unstable.

Comment: Depending on the kind of operations I want to perform with the third-party APIs, I've found that setting up a separate test account can work. 

I'm with you that at some point in the testing process you want to do away with mocks and actually talk to a real resource.

Also, if you're performing idempotent operations then talking to the real reource maybe be viable.

Comment: back to your questions- what are you looking for ? a technical solution ? because as I said the common practice is a test pyramid- a lot unit tests, some integration tests (mocks belong here) and very few end to end tests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it a normal practice to create a fake Github account with fake data that would be fetched by my tests ?

Yes. The purpose of an E2E test (vs an integration test) is to verify that the full system works with all the real system components in place, both the ones you control and the ones you don't. This can be hard to setup and a pain to maintain; but many of those pain points will be  exposing real potential issues in your production service. How your service responds to that instability is itself a feature to be tested: does your system crash and burn, or does it gracefully present an error message and support good retry handling?

This also nets you a type of coverage that mocks cannot provide: If the third party API you're using is naughty and introduces some sort of breaking change, your E2E tests will catch it. This is a decent reason to continually run your E2E suite; not just during deploys.

The next level of this sort of testing is [chaos engineering](https://principlesofchaos.org/) where not only do you test your production systems, but you purposefully introduce faults (yes, into prod) in order to ensure that your service can really handle the pressure.

> And what to do with access tokens, not all services are public and even public services can fail with rate limit.

Your staging environment should be configured with separate sandbox accounts for external services. I'm not sure what you mean by "not all services are public" but just strive to keep your staging environment (or test users on prod) as identical to a real prod user as possible. For services that don't support multiple access tokens, you can get creative and try to clearly delineate your test data within their system.

Rate limits can be annoying, but if you're getting close enough that your tests push you over the limit, then you should be pursuing a strategy to address that anyways (negotiating with the service, getting multiple accounts, ...).

Answer (score 5):

Running your tests against 3rd party services can result in slow and flaky tests when the service is down or when network latency triggers certain testing timeouts. Not to mention you run the risk of triggering API rate limits depending on the 3rd party service you're hitting. Your tests should ideally be deterministic, not failing randomly, and not needing conditional logic to handle errors within a particular test case. If you expect to need to handle errors, then there should be a specific test case to cover those errors that runs in every build, not waiting for non-deterministic failures to come in from the 3rd party.

One argument people will make is that your tests should notify you if the 3rd party API breaks for one reason or another. Generally speaking, though, most major 3rd party APIs are extremely stable and are unlikely to make breaking changes. Even if it does happen, this is an awkward and confusing way to find out that the API is broken, and in all likelihood, your tests aren't going to be the first place you hear it from. More likely your customers and your production error tracker will notify you. If you want to track when these services change or go down, it makes sense to have a regular production check of some sort to verify it.

As for how to write tests around these situations, that's a little more tricky. There are tools such as [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) in Ruby which work well for stubbing out your language's internet connections and allowing you to stub out, record, and customize responses (there's a list of similar implementations in other languages further down in their readme). That doesn't work for when your browser connects to those resources in automated end-to-end tests, though. There are tools that proxy your browser's web connection such as [Puffing Billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) in Ruby, but it's a pretty involved process to set up, including managing security certificates. This seems pretty brittle and hard to debug when something isn't working quite right.

Your best bet for writing tests that are deterministic and maintainable may be to fake out the service in test mode. [thoughtbot has a pretty decent video](https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/testing-interaction-with-3rd-party-apis) on this and [here's a high-level article from CircleCI](https://circleci.com/blog/testing-3rd-party-apis-and-microservices/). Essentially, you swap in an adapter in test mode that stands in for your 3rd party service integration. Maybe what you can do on your local machine is make it possible to optionally use the real service or the adapter via an environment variable in order to verify that the tests run the same against both. You could also set up a daily build to run against the real thing so that it would verify that the tests still work alright without introducing a lot of flakiness to your more frequent builds. One issue I've run into, though, is that even if I set up a test account on that 3rd party service, the results will change over time as I add or modify information for the sake of testing new functionality, such as adding new repos, modifying issues, etc. It requires additional consideration for maintaining your test account as a set of fixtures for all of your tests.

One additional tool I've come across that may be helpful is the likes of [ngrok-tunnel](https://github.com/bogdanovich/ngrok-tunnel) (Ruby again). This is only relevant in cases where you need the 3rd party service to contact your app, since they can't send requests across the web to `localhost:3000`. If you've configured some sort of webhooks, services like this can make testing a lot more straightforward.